# MX record lookup only hits first record

Tags: email, dns

Basically I have a situation like this:
The website owner has some email setup through gmail's servers, probably whatever was the default way to do it.  When I setup my own smtp server on the host, I can bypass his system with a lower priority MX record, but then he doesn't get emails from the old system.  If I set a higher priority for my MX record, I don't get the emails.  It's like google only tries the first record and then gives up.  Any idea why this could be happening?  I was able to add an A-record and send to server.website.com, but that seemed like a clunky work around.  Shouldn't google try all of the MX records when I ask it to send mail to my domain?  I do make sure to check the record's deployment status with dig or nslookup.  These are active records.

Edit for clarity:

It's basically like emailA@website.com goes through when my MX record is higher numbered priority than his.  When I drop my priority to 0 for the MX record and send an email to the new address like emailB@website.com, my emailB@website.com works but then the other one gets the 550 response.  In other words, only the highest priority lookup is used and then instead of checking the other MX records it just throws 550 from the mail server tied to the first MX record.  Is that standard behavior?

Comment: If the delivery to lower MX succeeds, sending MTA will not try to deliver to other MX records.

Comment: Its a situation where its failing to find the address from then first record and the not checking the others.  I edited for clarity.